# Employer on Profile - Mismatching

Tags: profile, duplicate-contacts

I saw a few with similar questions, but not exactly the same on a major point. If moderators see value in merging this, go for it.

We have a problem where people sign up for an event which includes Current Employer on the profile. When that gets saved to their contact, it often maps to the wrong organization - one that starts the same. Even if we type out the full name of the organization exactly right, it will pair it with another organization instead. It seems like it is only able to store the first 10-20 characters and then matching to the first organization it finds starting with those characters. This happens a lot when you're dealing with a lot of organizations named starting with the city/region.

This is on Version 4.6.31 with Drupal but the client has said this has been an issue for about a year, so it's not a new version bug.

Any better ways around this than creating another custom field which they would need to manually copy into the auto-select Employer field from the back end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching to existing organisations is determined by the Unsupervised rule for Organisations - go to `Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts` then click `Edit Rule` on the rule marked Unsupervised to see how it is currently defined.  You can change the existing rule, or create a new one and set its usage to Unsupervised.

Alternatively, you might find this extension useful: https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names

Comment: Thank you! I knew about those settings but it didn't cross my mind they would be used for Current Employer on profiles.

They had some very odd decisions with their default matching rule. I changed it to name only and my test went through properly with no issue.